# How to Build Autocomplete Multiple tagging in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have to build Autocomplete multiple tagging with laravel. Did research a lot but stuck with the problem. I also read the laravel tags and also going through with Bootstrap tagging.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags

But the problems in my MySQL version does not support JSON datatype so any other ways to do it without upgrading MySQL version or some other kinds of the library in laravel to build such functionality.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

To store your json in mysql database first u need to encode it.

For laravel json::encode() function u need to use.

And for retrieve you need to decode using json::decode() function.